# How can I replace original base URL to my custom URL?

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, routes, url-routing

When anyone goto **mydomain.com** then I want just rename to **hellodomain.com** base URL without refreshing. That's mean there is no relation between mydomain & hellodomain. So whenever you go, you will see hellodomain instead of mydoamin.

Is it possible by using javascript? If then how can I do this?

Comment: You can't do it. It's a security risk, so browsers block it. You can only do a redirect to a domain, but not change it without reload the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible at the javascript level

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this using PHP.

```
$handle = curl_init();
 
$url = "https://example.com";
 
// Set the url
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
// Set the result output to be a string.
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 
$output = curl_exec($handle);
 
curl_close($handle);
 
print_r($output);
```